# Как в Windows посмотреть свойства файла?

Tags: windows

Т.е. как полностью отобразить строку после многоточия «...»? Я что только не пробовал.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потянуть за границу заголовка столбца, подчеркнул красным, после этого появится горизонтальный scrollbar

[image: screen]

Comment: Отлично!!! Спасибо!!!

Comment: А как скопировать знаете?

Comment: Путь можно скопировать правой кнопкой с зажатым shift "копировать как путь", как скопировать свойство без стороннего софта не знаю